# Помогите разобраться с ESLint?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

Eslint указывает на ошибку, хочет чтоб я использовал двойные кавычки, мне нужны одинарные. Установил настройку, но при этом он все равно плачет на кавычки.
Даже после сохранения.
Мой файл .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:vue/essential', 'eslint:recommended', '@vue/prettier'],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
  rules: {
    quotes: [2, 'single', { avoidEscape: true }],
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
  },
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну наверное должно быть что-то вроде `quotes: ["error", "single", { "avoidEscape": true }]`, судя по [докам](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes)

Comment: module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:vue/essential', 'eslint:recommended', '@vue/prettier'],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
  rules: {
    quotes: ['error', 'single', { avoidEscape: true }],
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
  },
};

Comment: Переделал, но, все равно жалуется на одинарные(

Comment: Так у вас там правила prettier, а не eslint.

Comment: @AlexeyTen да. В vue cli выбирал связку eslint + prettier

Comment: @AlexeyTen а, как должно быть? Нужно выбирать eslint + stantart?

Comment: Ну преттиер известен своей бескомпромиссностью. Так что «вы не хотите одиночные кавычки»

Comment: Либо вам не нужен преттир

Comment: @AlexeyTen при сохранении претиер, автоматически раставляет одинарные кавычки, а еслинт требует двойные. Уже сколько уроков пересмотрел, и делаю по докам quotes: ["error", "single", { "avoidEscape": true }], но, это все равно не работает, не могу понять, какую конфигурацию нужно выбирать тогда и почему правило не срабатывает(

Comment: @AlexeyTen prettier правильно делает, ставит одинарные, это eslint хочет двойные, вот и хочу поменять правила eslint\

Comment: На вашем скриншоте русским языком написано `prettier/prettier`. Так что «не верю» ©

Comment: `rules: { 'prettier/prettier': ['warn', { singleQuote: true }], },` - не?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы включить использование одинарных кавычек пропиши в файле .prettierrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  singleQuote: true,
};
```

…применится после перезагрузки